# Music and sound effects don’t play on win32 platform? (cocos2d-x)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

When I run my game on win32 platform, my sounds don't play. But sounds are playing normally in android platform.

I'm using:

```
auto audio = CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance();
audio->playEffect("sounds/jump.ogg");
```

How can fix this? thanks

Comment: Could be as simple as requiring a full path for the file name. And I don't know why this is being downvoted, it includes code and a description of the symptom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to cocos2d-x [wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Audio#Supported-Audio-formats-on-different-platforms),  `.mid` and `.wav` only supported on window desktop.

**Sound Effects**

```
|    Platform     |   supported sound effects formats   |
|-----------------|:-----------------------------------:|
| Android Supports|         .ogg , .wav format.         |
| iOS             |          .mp3, .wav, .caf           |   
| Windows Desktop |         .mid and .wav only          |
```

Above file format table is for `SimpleAudioEngine`, currently I am using `.ogg` file on win32 desktop with new experimental `AudioEngine`

```
#include "audio/include/AudioEngine.h"

experimental::AudioEngine::play2d("sounds/jump.ogg", false, 1.0);
```